# Screenshots are not uploading on Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I have made one app live today and everything was working fine. The app was available within an hour after upload. After that I have changed the name of app and uploaded that again and that also worked fine and everything was OK and successfully updated on play store.

Now the problem starts. When I realized that screenshots are not proper I'm going to change that and trying to upload another one, but when I upload the images it shows only android icon jumping over progress bar and nothing is going to upload. When I tried that previous images, same problem is there and nothing is working .

I'm not able to figure out what problem is going all.

Can anyone help me to find out the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with another web browser?

Comment: @SoothSayer no i m doing that with safari

Comment: I'm having the same problems here, perhaps an issue on google's side?

Comment: Same problem here. Can't even upload an apk file.

Comment: Yup, it's a Google issue. Guess they'll fix it Monday.

Comment: still not fixed on Monday evening (tried with Chrome, Opera, IE), going home and retrying tomorrow...

Answer (score 3):

It appears that it's google's problem i can't upload neither images nor apks.I first tried almost 24 hours ago. Keep trying to upload your images. If they get successfully uploaded then google play will "tell" you  if they are proper or not (that's for the dimensions/properties of the image not it's content).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I think my original answer was sufficient for the OP's question. He was wondering what was the issue behind not being able to upload he's images and i said it's google's problem cause i am having the same